# Mule - Database Connector - Insert - Parameter Type as Expression or Bean Reference ( Oracle Data Type RAW(16) | GUID | UUID )

Tags: oracle, mule, mulesoft, mule4

How can I correct use the **Parameter Types** as an **Expression or Bean reference** for example when using **Insert** operation of the **MuleSoft Database Connector**?

- [Configure Database Connector Data Types Examples - Mule 4 | Configure the Parameter Types Field in Studio | MuleSoft Documentation   (docs.mulesoft.com)](https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.13/database-configure-data-types#configure-the-parameter-types-field-in-studio)
- [Database Connector Reference 1.13 - Mule 4 | Parameter Type Definition | MuleSoft Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.13/database-documentation#ParameterType)

[image: image_print_studio_parameter-types_database_connector-mule]

Because we need to dynamic pass a reference for a non default type in database. For example, in **Oracle** we have the `RAW(16)` that when using the [**Input Parameters**](https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.13/database-connector-select#configure-the-input-parameters-field-in-the-select-operation) it gets the error:

```
Message               : Invalid column type: 1111.
Error type            : DB:QUERY_EXECUTION
```

So, we need **Parameter Types** as explained in the documentation below:

- [Configure Database Connector Data Types Examples - Mule 4 | MuleSoft Documentation (docs.mulesoft.com)](https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.13/database-configure-data-types)

One way that I tried is: `[{'key': "ID", 'type': "LONGNVARCHAR"}]`

In the XML:

```xml
    <db:insert doc:name="Insert" doc:id="4ee50969-884b-4eb7-93e0-adca25229683" 
        config-ref="Database_Config_Oracle"
        queryTimeoutUnit="DAYS" 
        autoGenerateKeys="true" 
        parameterTypes="#[[{'key': &quot;ID&quot;, 'type': &quot;LONGNVARCHAR&quot;}]]">
        <db:sql><![CDATA[#[ vars.db.query ]]]></db:sql>
        <db:input-parameters><![CDATA[#[vars.db.inputParameters]]]></db:input-parameters>
        <db:auto-generated-keys-column-names />
    </db:insert>
```

But this way it gets the error:

```java
""java.lang.IllegalStateException - No read or write handler for type
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No read or write handler for type
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.reader.PropertyDefinition._type$lzycompute(PropertyDefinition.scala:44)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.reader.PropertyDefinition._type(PropertyDefinition.scala:35)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.reader.PropertyDefinition.classType(PropertyDefinition.scala:70)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.writer.entry.BeanPropertyEntry.entryType(BeanPropertyEntry.scala:24)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.writer.WriterEntry.putValue(WriterEntry.scala:18)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.writer.WriterEntry.putValue$(WriterEntry.scala:11)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.writer.entry.BeanPropertyEntry.putValue(BeanPropertyEntry.scala:19)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.writer.JavaWriter.write(JavaWriter.scala:62)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.writer.JavaWriter.writeSimpleJavaValue(JavaWriter.scala:419)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.writer.JavaWriter.doWriteValue(JavaWriter.scala:268)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.WriterWithAttributes.internalWriteValue(WriterWithAttributes.scala:35)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.WriterWithAttributes.internalWriteValue$(WriterWithAttributes.scala:34)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.writer.JavaWriter.internalWriteValue(JavaWriter.scala:44)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.WriterWithAttributes.writeAttributesAndValue(WriterWithAttributes.scala:30)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.WriterWithAttributes.writeAttributesAndValue$(WriterWithAttributes.scala:15)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.writer.JavaWriter.writeAttributesAndValue(JavaWriter.scala:44)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.writer.JavaWriter.doWriteValue(JavaWriter.scala:241)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.Writer.writeValue(Writer.scala:65)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.Writer.writeValue$(Writer.scala:46)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.writer.JavaWriter.writeValue(JavaWriter.scala:44)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.writer.JavaWriter.doWriteValue(JavaWriter.scala:216)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.Writer.writeValue(Writer.scala:65)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.Writer.writeValue$(Writer.scala:46)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.writer.JavaWriter.writeValue(JavaWriter.scala:44)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.java.JavaInvocationHelper$.transformToJavaCollection(JavaInvokeFunction.scala:105)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.utils.DataTypeHelper$.transformToJava(DataTypeHelper.scala:166)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.utils.DataTypeHelper$.transformToJavaDataType(DataTypeHelper.scala:153)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.utils.DataTypeHelper$.toJavaValue(DataTypeHelper.scala:104)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.evaluate(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:253)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.$anonfun$evaluate$4(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:135)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.doEvaluate(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:268)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.evaluate(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:134)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.el.dataweave.DataWeaveExpressionLanguageAdaptor$1.evaluate(DataWeaveExpressionLanguageAdaptor.java:321)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.el.DefaultExpressionManagerSession.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManagerSession.java:117)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.util.attribute.ExpressionAttributeEvaluatorDelegate.resolveExpressionWithSession(ExpressionAttributeEvaluatorDelegate.java:68)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.util.attribute.ExpressionAttributeEvaluatorDelegate.resolve(ExpressionAttributeEvaluatorDelegate.java:56)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.util.AttributeEvaluator.resolveTypedValue(AttributeEvaluator.java:107)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.resolver.ExpressionValueResolver.resolveTypedValue(ExpressionValueResolver.java:115)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.resolver.ExpressionValueResolver.resolve(ExpressionValueResolver.java:99)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.resolver.TypeSafeValueResolverWrapper.lambda$initialise$0(TypeSafeValueResolverWrapper.java:69)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.resolver.TypeSafeValueResolverWrapper.resolve(TypeSafeValueResolverWrapper.java:52)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.resolver.TypeSafeExpressionValueResolver.resolve(TypeSafeExpressionValueResolver.java:73)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.resolver.ResolverUtils.resolveRecursively(ResolverUtils.java:92)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.resolver.ResolverSet.resolve(ResolverSet.java:113)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.getResolutionResult(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:1258)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.addContextToEvent(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:762)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.lambda$null$5(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:354)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:273)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:496)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:490)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:485)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:351)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnValue$ScheduledScalar.run(FluxSubscribeOnValue.java:178)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:50)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:27)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:151)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748), while writing Java at 
1| [{'key': "ID", 'type': "LONGNVARCHAR"}]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^.
1| [{'key': "ID", 'type': "LONGNVARCHAR"}]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at anonymous::main (line: 1, column: 2)" evaluating expression: "[{'key': "ID", 'type': "LONGNVARCHAR"}]"."
```

Reference: [Database Connector Data Types Examples - Parameter Types | How to write as **Expression or Bean reference** · Issue #2050 · mulesoft/docs-connectors (github.com)](https://github.com/mulesoft/docs-connectors/issues/2050)

Comment: Did you try following the instructions using Studio? Does it create an attribute parameterTypes or an element? Where did you see it can be an attribute?

Comment: @aled as showed in the [doc I linked](https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.13/database-configure-data-types#configure-the-parameter-types-field-in-studio), when I choose **Edit Inline** it creates an element inside `<db:insert>` for example `<db:parameter-types><db:parameter-type key="ID" type="LONGVARCHAR" /></db:parameter-types>`. I understood that type is a keyword, because of this, my try was `[{'key': "ID", 'type': "LONGNVARCHAR"}]`

Comment: That shows that `<parameter -types>` is an XML element. You are using parameterTyoes  it as an XML attribute. Where did you see it as an attribute?

Comment: When I choose the **Expression or Bean reference** the studio puts as an attribute, I didn't see as an attribute and write the XML for my own. The documentation doesn't show an example for writing as **Expression or Bean reference**, so I assumed that I could pass the array `[{'key': "ID", 'type': "LONGNVARCHAR"}]` and it would be the same as the element `db:parameter-types`

Comment: @aled The documentation shows how to use **Edit Inline** (Studio puts as an **element**). My question is to help me clarify how to use **Expression or Bean reference** (Studio puts as an **attribute**) as showed in the print I attached.

Comment: I understand your test now. It is not documented unfortunately. I suspect the expression is just to refer to a bean rather than to use to the result of evaluating it.